# How can I remove an array element by index,using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to remove an array's element by its index?

For example

```
fruits = ["mango","apple","pine","berry"];
```

Remove element fruits[2] to get

```
fruits = ["mango","apple","berry"];
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use `splice` as: `array.splice(start_index, no_of_elements_to_remove)`. Here's the solution to your example:

```js
const fruits = ["mango","apple","pine","berry"]; 
const removed = fruits.splice(2, 1); // Mutates fruits and returns array of removed items
console.log('fruits', fruits); // ["mango","apple","berry"]
console.log('removed', removed); // ["pine"]
```

This will remove one element from index 2, i.e. after the operation `fruits=["mango","apple","berry"];`

Comment: No idea why slice(i,j) in nodejs is get sub array from index i to j-1, and NOT remove at index i with j items!?